# Rstrip not removing correct backslashes or giving position

Tags: python

So,

I have a string that looks like \uisfhb\dfjn
This will vary in length. Im struggling to get my head around rsplit and the fact that backslash is an escape character. i only want "dfjn"
i currently have

```
 more = "\\\\uisfhb\dfjn"
 more = more.replace(r'"\\\\', r"\\") 
 sharename = more.rsplit(r'\\', 2)
 print(sharename)
```

and im getting back 
['', 'uisfhb\dfjn']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to partition a string on a literal backslash, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash in the separator.

```
>>> more.split('\\')
['', '', 'uisfhb', 'dfjn']

>>> more.rsplit('\\', 1)
['\\\\uisfhb', 'dfjn']

>>> more.rpartition('\\')
('\\\\uisfhb', '\\', 'dfjn')
```

Once the string has been split, the last element can be accessed using the index -1:

```
>>> sharename = more.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1]
>>> sharename
'dfjn'
```

or using sequence-unpacking syntax (the `*` operator)

```
>>> *_, sharename = more.rpartition('\\')
>>> sharename
'dfjn'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an issue with raw strings. Try this:

```
more = "\\\\uisfhb\dfjn"
more = more.replace("\\\\", "\\")
sharename = more.split("\\")[2] # using split and not rsplit
print(sharename)
```

Answer (score 0):

If sharename is the last node in the tree, this will get it:

```
 >>>more = "\\\\uisfhb\dfjn"
 >>>sharename = more.split('\\')[-1]
 >>>sharename
 'dfjn'
```